# Add lang argument in tweeter query

Tags: python, twitter

I have this code and i want to retrieve tweets about seminars in english.

this is my code. please how can i add parameters to my query ?

i have tried to add parameters with add_argument but it does not work.

```
import config


class TwitterListener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, output_dir, query):
        valid_chars = '-_.%s%s' % (string.ascii_letters, string.digits)
        query_fname = ''.join(c if c in valid_chars else '_' for c in query)
        self.outfile = "%s/stream_%s.json" % (output_dir, query_fname)

    def on_data(self, status):
        try:
            with open(self.outfile, 'a') as f:
                f.write(status)
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_status: %s" % str(e))
            time.sleep(5)

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            print(status_code)
            return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Twitter Scraper")
    parser.add_argument("-q", "--query", dest="query", help="Filter the twitter stream with this query.",
                        default='-')
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--output-dir", dest="output_dir", required=True,
                        help="Path to the directory in which you want to store the tweets.")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    authentication = OAuthHandler(config.consumer_key, config.consumer_secret)
    authentication.set_access_token(config.access_token, config.access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(authentication)

    twitter_stream = Stream(authentication, TwitterListener(args.output_dir, args.query))
    twitter_stream.filter(track=[args.query])
```